# Using Arduino Uno for my hardware AI assistant Project

Tags: arduino, iot, hardware, arduino-uno

I would like to know if I can use a Arduino Uno R3 for my Project.
Project Details: An AI assitant in an embedded system.
The AI is already written in Python

I tried to get a Raspberry Pi 0 but it is quite scarce in my location.I will like to know if there is a way for me to embed my python code on my Arduino UNO R3,SD card module and speaker

Comment: the ATmega328p on Uno has only 2kB of RAM. the SD cad needs a memory buffer of at least 0.5kB. there is no space for Python interpreter not so much for an AI brain

Answer (score 0):

No, there's no way that will all fit into an Arduino Uno (or any AVR-based Arduino). They all have not enough RAM. And there's (as far as I know) no python interpreter for the uno as well, for the same reason. You could try an ESP32 instead. Much more RAM, much more powerful CPU, micropython support (and typically even cheaper).